# Flot break line chart - why?

Tags: flot

For the following data, I receive dis-continuous line chart.

There are lines for 
  `07:10..07:50`, 
  `08:10..08:50`, 
  `09:10..09:50`,

but Flot ignores the values at `08:00, 09:00` (why?)
and does not connect lines from `07:50 to 08:10` (why?)

In what cases Flot decide to "break" line charts?

```
07:20   10/03/2016  25.4    24.2    24.7
07:30   10/03/2016  25.2    23.9    24.3
07:40   10/03/2016  25.1    23.8    24.3
07:50   10/03/2016  25.1    23.8    24.3
08:00   10/03/2016  25.1    23.8    24.3
08:10   10/03/2016  25.1    23.9    24.3
08:20   10/03/2016  24.9    24.2    24.3
08:30   10/03/2016  24.9    24.2    24.3
08:40   10/03/2016  24.9    24.2    24.3
08:50   10/03/2016  25      24.5    24.6
09:00   10/03/2016  25.1    24.6    24.7
09:10   10/03/2016  25.2    24.6    24.8
09:20   10/03/2016  25.2    24.6    24.8
09:30   10/03/2016  25.2    24.6    24.7
09:40   10/03/2016  25.2    24.6    24.7
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that generates the timestamps for flot and the original data.

Comment: What is the format of your data as Flot reads it? From the [Flot documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format): "a null value for lines is interpreted as a line segment end, i.e. the points before and after the null value are not connected."

Comment: @Raidri - "original data" - that was the source of the problem

Comment: @mechenbier - "null values" was the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it - it happens when hours\minutes in CSV are "0" and my code was expecting "00",

-> no UTC generated,

-> null value,

-> chart-line break.

I saw it only when I opened the csv in text editor.

When opened in Excel, Excel seems to set the values into correct format!

```
v  7:50, 10/3/2016,25.1,23.8,24.3,52.9,0.0,24.0
x  8:0,  10/3/2016,25.1,23.8,24.3,54.2,0.0,24.0   <- the chart breaks.
v  8:10, 10/3/2016,25.1,23.9,24.3,52.8,0.0,24.1
v  8:50, 10/3/2016,25.0,24.5,24.6,49.6,0.0,24.5
x  9:0,  10/3/2016,25.1,24.6,24.7,48.3,0.0,24.6   <- the chart breaks.
v  9:10, 10/3/2016,25.2,24.6,24.8,47.6,0.0,24.7
v  9:20, 10/3/2016,25.2,24.6,24.8,47.1,0.0,24.7
```